# Como implementar duas Request para validar campos de pessoa Física e Jurídica?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Caso o tipo de pessoa selecionado seja **F** é valido através da `FisicaRequest`

```
public function store(FisicaRequest $reqFisica, JuridicaRequest $reqJuridica)
{
    if ($reqFisica->tipo_pessoa == "F") {

        $data = $reqFisica->all();
        Devedor::create($data);
        return redirect()->route('admin.devedors.index');
    }
    if ($reqJuridica->tipo_pessoa == "J") {

        $data = $reqJuridica->all();
        Devedor::create($data);
        return redirect()->route('admin.devedors.index');
    }
}
```

Porém não estou conseguindo que o pessoa jurídica seja validado pelo JuridicaRequest.

Comment: usa o validate do request e valida quantos digitos está sendo passado dom min e max

Comment: o segundo request é populado? como o framework faz para saber qual objeto deve ser injetado? acredito que dois requests no mesmo método não vá funcionar

Comment: No pedido Http, só tem um Request, pode utilizar diferentes lógicas de validação no FormRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No próprio `RequestForm`se pode criar a decisão que quiser e não precisa criar dois para a validação um só com um `if` dentro você consegue ter o mesmo efeito, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PeopleRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $data = array();
        if ($this->get('tipo_pessoa') === 'F')
        {
            // validações da pessoa fisica
            $data[... // validações
        }
        else
        {
           // validações da pessoa jurídica ou diferente de física
           $data[... // validações
        } 
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Nesse `if`(*decisão*) pode resgatar o elemento enviado pelo `form`(*formulário*) e isso te dá um desvio na validação corresponde do tipo de usuário.

Comment: Porque eu recebi um voto negativo? tem alguma explicação, tem algo para arrumar ou é simplesmente uma forma de coibir, de perseguição, se tiver algo de errado pode dizer estou aqui para arrumar também, afinal somos todos humanos.

Answer (score 1):

Esse caso você pode usar uma requisição dentro do controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 if ($request->tipo_pessoa == "F") {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
}

if ($request->tipo_pessoa == "J") {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
}

}
```